# angular primeng datatable get filtered data

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to get all the filter data from table, suppose i have

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="list" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selection"  [rows]="2"[paginator]="true" >
       <p-column selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
       <p-column field="description" header="description" [filter]="true"></p-column>
```

now once i do filter the rows, and do a select all, i want to select all the rows which are filter, only only in that particular page, but across all pagination.

I have tried, this.dt.dataToRender, but it only provides data that is filtered but its only limited to that particular page.

Answer (score 2):

Set this property `headerCheckboxToggleAllPages` to true.

From the [**Documentation**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable)

> When set to true, the header checkbox on paged DataTables with
>   checkbox multiple selection enabled will toggle the selection of items
>   across all pages

This is an [**Example**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/selection)

Comment: is this property available in version 2.0.6? i am getting this message on that vesion Can't bind to 'headerCheckboxToggleAllPages' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dataTable'.

Comment: No, this is a new property added after about 4+

Comment: any solution to do this in angular 2 than?

Comment: Why not upgrade?

Comment: can't update to angular 4, hence can't update to primeng 4 either

Comment: either way i have looked at the code here https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/a95c7e580987a2349b5a5c284ffe22d49a8e8c61/src/app/components/datatable/datatable.ts, and it doesn't look like they itself are only selecting values which are filtered across the pages, they are blindly taking all the values